# How to find link in a row in a table and then click on another link in same row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am trying to click link in a row, which has another link that has name variable o.customer_id

Basically,I want to click a link "Action" which is in the same row as the link which has customer's id(which is variable)

I have tried using this but has not worked:

```
find(:xpath, link(have_content(o.customer_id)), :text => 'Action').click
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parenthesis after the click to trigger it. I.e. click()
Also open the JavaScript console in your browser and make sure that find return a link element in your page.